# How to move an image in Flutter/Dart using a draggable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a simple children's game that allows the user to click on an image and drag it to a DragTarget. The images will eventually contain dynamic text from a list, but they currently just contain a number to simulate that. Currently when I select on the image only the text will move. The image itself stays still. What I eventually want is for the image to disappear from the screen once it is delivered to the DragTarget. I have tried a few variations of the code below but nothing has worked. I am assuming I will have to use some form of GestureDetector but I have failed to successfully implement one (my code does not show those attempts). Any help or advice is much appreciated!

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("assets/images/landscape_with_tree.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DragBox(Offset(250.0, 50.0), '1'),
        DragBox(Offset(350.0, 50.0), '2'),
        DragBox(Offset(200.0, 100.0), '3'),
        Positioned(
          right: 50.0,
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: DragTarget(
//            onAccept: () {
//            },
            builder: (
              BuildContext context,
              List<dynamic> accepted,
              List<dynamic> rejected,
            ) {
              return Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/basket.png"),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Drag Here!',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),

  }
```

**Draggable Class**

```
class _DragBoxState extends State<DragBox> {
  Offset position = Offset(0.0, 0.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: position.dx,
      top: position.dy,
      child: Draggable(
        child: Container(
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/apple.png"),
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              widget.label,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
          setState(() {
            position = widget.initPos;
          });
        },
        feedback: Container(
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              widget.label,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient or best way of doing it but I got the following solution to work. Please let me know if you have a better way!

```
class _DragBoxState extends State<DragBox> {
  Offset position = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
  AssetImage apple;
  AssetImage _imageToShow = new AssetImage('assets/images/apple.png');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    position = widget.initPos;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: position.dx,
      top: position.dy,
      child: Draggable<AssetImage>(
        data: apple,
        child: Container(
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: _imageToShow,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              widget.label,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
          setState(() {
            position = widget.initPos;
          });
        },
        onDragStarted: () {
          setState(() {
            print('drag started');
            _imageToShow = new AssetImage('assets/images/answered_apple.png');
            return _imageToShow;
          });
        },
        feedback: Container(
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: _imageToShow,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              widget.label,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code was not working for me..(i am new to flutter). If possible, could you please share the code?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for, but the answer above is the piece of the code that the question is referring to.